# Error:(15, 30) java: incompatible types: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Param cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I got this error while running my java code (spring) ;
Error:(15, 30) java: incompatible types: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Param cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation. 
"email" and "password" are underlined and shows errors, this is my code :

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/test", collectionResourceRel = "test")
public interface JpaService extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

@RestResource(exported = false)
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person AS p WHERE p.email =:email AND p.password =:password")
public Person login(@Param("email") String email , @Param("password")String password);

@RestResource(exported = false)
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person AS p WHERE p.email =:email")
public Person getPersonByEmail(@Param("email") String email);


}
```

Comment: I suspect you're using the wrong import. Remove the line ``import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Param;`` and see what other imports are suggested, it's probably supposed to be one of spring's classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Param` import is wrong. Use `org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param` instead. The class you imported is no Annotation, therefore the error.

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question then you might want to accept it as correct answer and/or upvote. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers